# Why did I lose some hundreds of reputation points this week?

Tags: soporte, reputación

I reached 10,000 a couple days ago - a personal goal of mine, so I noticed -- and then I gained a few more points.  But now I'm at 9766.  The only negative change I can find is that someone changed their mind about which answer to accept.  (I agree, by the way, the new answer is more useful for the OP.)  But that only accounts for 15 points.  Can anyone help me figure out what's going on?

Did someone remove some of their questions, that perhaps I had some upvoted answers connected to?  Remove their account?

Did the company decide to undo the higher point value for questions?

Comment: Checking on last dump of SEDE, which dates on Jan 26 2020, [your reputation until gained until Jan 26 2020](https://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/882556/?Userid=9385&untildate=2020-02-01) shows 9832, which is above your current 9766. This sounds weird. Also, it shows [513 answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/1190444/?Userid=9385), below your current 520,  and [65 questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/1190444/?UserId=9385), same number as now. Don't really know what can be happening here. Have you checked https://spanish.stackexchange.com/reputation ?

Comment: Thanks for the research.  I didn't understand the column headings -- but I have a new guess.  Maybe the decrease is due to some bounties being retracted, perhaps from some user(s) removing their accounts?

Comment: No, bounties are awarded and the reputation goes to you. There are not rollbacked if the user disappears, simply because it is now your reputation and not theirs. Have you checked your Deleted Recent Answers and Questions?

Comment: This might be a question for the CMs (unfortunately, because they take a really long time to answer), because it seems that users here, even with mod privileges, won't have enough information to look into this (beyond the "a user was removed" or similar).

Comment: @fedorqui - it looks like this is one of those mysteries of life and I am unlikely to get an answer.  I hope you don't mind if I roll my title back.  I don't want the focus to be on me specifically.  I was curious if the change in my rep was part of some system change that I hadn't noticed.

Comment: As you wish. I checked via https://web.archive.org but could not find a recent snapshot of your profile, so it is difficult to trace.